# How to set MAXSPLIT option while sending SMS via Email?

Tags: email, sms

I am using SMSGlobal's EMAIL-2-SMS API to send SMSs to client's mobile phones via email.
Everything's simple & straightforward. But when I send a message that is more than 160 chars, it gets truncated after 160th char.
The API has a provision to send these kind of messages in multiple parts by using MAXSPLIT option.
If I use HTTP API, I can set MAXSPLIT like below example
http://www.smsglobal.com/httpapi.php?action=sendsms&user=testuser&password=secret&to=61447100250&text=Hello%20world&api=1&userfield=61728&maxsplit=3

But how do I set that in Email message?

Thank you
Reddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done dynamically or on per message basis! We have to change the preferences in SMSGlobal preferences page.